# Jenkins Authentication using IBM Tivoli Access Manager

Tags: authentication, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am considering integrating IBM's Tivoli Access Manager with Jenkins for user authentication.  TAM uses something called a WebSeal to allow users to login and then forwards the creds for that user in the HTTP header to the desired service.  I am new to Jenkins and was wondering what would be the easiest approach to do this.  I noticed that the existing OpenId plugin extends the FederatedLoginService currently present in Jenkins.  Could something similar be done to integrate TAM?  If not, where would I extend Jenkins to allow the extraction of the creds form the header provided by WebSeal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using [the Tomcat adapter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021393) for TAM, and run Jenkins in a Tomcat container with security realm *Delegate to servlet container* (untested).

Comment: There's also a [Script Security Realm](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Realm) plugin that allows you to write a custom (shell) script for authenticating if all else fails.

Comment: As an alternative to the first approach, there's also [Delegate to ReverseProxy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin) -- you can run Jenkins behind an Apache reverse proxy and let Apache handle the authentication (there's probably an out-of-the-box solution for that for TAM).

Comment: I probably won't be able to introduce additional components/software into my solution.  The environment is too tightly controlled.  The only options I have available are going to be those already provided by Jenkins or a custom plugin.  I wasn't aware of the Security Script Realm plugin so I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I'm thinking I will have to extend PluginImpl, AuthorizationStrategy, GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy, ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy, SecurityRealm within Jenkins to do this. Not only do I have to get Jenkins to accept identities, but also I have to map roles/groups from TAM to the roles defined via the Role Strategy Plugin in Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

To make @daniel-beck’s suggestion into a concrete answer: the [Reverse Proxy Auth plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin) is the way this sort of integration is normally done in the absence of a dedicated SSO plugin, though I do not know specifically whether WebSEAL sends headers suitable for consumption by this plugin. From what I can [glean by searching](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/SC32-1134-01/en_US/HTML/amweb41_admin12.htm), you would get `HTTP_IV_USER` and `HTTP_IV_GROUPS`.